# Connected Google Sheets don't allow for filtering

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet in a Google Sheet called "Call_log". It has three columns: Name, Call Date, and Call Type.

Call_log basically tracks all engagements with people. For example, if on June 12th, I had a call with a person named John Smith, it would populate the following:

Name: John Smith
Call Date: June 12th
Call Type: Work phone

If I spoke to John Smith again on June 13th, but over my home phone, it would populate the following:

Name: John Smith
Call Date: June 13th
Call Type: Home phone

There can be multiple rows for a person in  "Call_log".

Here's an example of the "Call_log" sheet:

| Name | Call Date | Call Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | June 5th, 2023 | Home phone |
| John Smith | June 2nd, 2023 | Mobile |
| Bob Billy | June 3rd, 2023 | Mobile |

I would like to take the data from "Call_log" and populate the new sheet "Call_log_enrich".

I would like "Call_log_enrich" to have the following columns:

Name
Last Call Date
Location of Person

"Name" would correspond to the name of the person and "Last Call Date" would be the date of the last recorded call of that person in "Call_log". "Location of Person" will be a manually populated column with the location of the person (for example, NYC, Dallas, Denver, etc.)

In the "Call_log_enrich" sheet, I would also like to filter by Name, Last Call Date, or Location of Person. So whatever solution that is offered, I would like it to take into account the fact that I need to filter.

Here's an example of the "Call_log_enrich" sheet:

| Name | Last Call Date | Location of Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | June 5th, 2023 | NYC |
| Bob Billy | June 3rd, 2023 | Dubai |

How can I create the "Call_log_enrich" sheet and what formula do I need to use to build it?

I have used solutions with ARRAY, SORT, FILTER, and UNIQUE functions, but whenever I filter by the manually-entered "Location of Person" column, it moves the equations around in the first two columns ("Name" and "Last Call Date") and I get a ton of blank cells.

Comment: I would just put what you describe into a dialog and forget the second sheet

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: A dialog to display a history of the callers activity in your log.  I'd probably use a select to choose from a list callers in the current log and additional controls to create callers that don't yet exist.  I'd probably use the dialog to add and edit all the content in the log.  Here's an example dialog I use to build SO data tables from spreadsheets

Comment: Regarding @Cooper 's suggestion. You are already entering three data elements into the call log; why complicate things? Just add the extra two extra fields to the call log - do you need a dialog to do that?

Comment: As Tedinoz and I point out  what you require is up to you.  Our mission here is to help you with the script.  The design is up to you.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to supply sample data for the "Call-log" and "Call_log_enrich" sheets, and also provide an example of a successful filter outcome.

Comment: So, I simplified the problem. The actual "Call_log_enrich" sheet has a few more columns that I'd like to be able to filter by. To be honest, I still don't understand the dialog solution.

Comment: I added some example data

Comment: @Cooper you said `Here's an example dialog I use to build SO data tables from spreadsheets`, but there's no link in that comment. Would you please repost with a link.